# Outbound mailer service not generating emails until restart

Tags: 2013-sp1, outbound-email

We are using Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 .Suddenly outbound mailer service stopped generating emails once we restart the service it generates the email and stopped we have to repeat this process each time to send emails inside outbound email logger file the error is listed as below

```
[Error] ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: oracle.xml.sql.OracleXMLSQLException: 'java.sql.SQLException: Recursive execution of a java.sql.Statement in the server' encountered during processing ROW element 5.  All prior XML row changes were rolled back. in the XML document.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLSAVE", line 115
ORA-06512: at "SH_OEDB.MAILINGS_SAVE_LINKURLS", line 15
ORA-06512: at line 1
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.DataSession.OpenRecordsetByStoredProcedure(UserContext userContext, String sProcName, Dictionary`2 parameters, Dictionary`2 outputParameters, Int32 timeoutSeconds)
2018-02-27T09:10:53 [Error] Stored procedure failed: SP_MAILINGS_SAVE_LINKURLS
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.DataSession.OpenRecordsetByStoredProcedure(UserContext userContext, String sProcName, Dictionary`2 parameters, Dictionary`2 outputParameters, Int32 timeoutSeconds)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.MailingDal.SaveLinkUrls(TcmUri mailingURI, EmailLinkUrls linkUrls)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.MailerBatches.FetchedMessage.UpdateTmsLinksInRenderdContent()
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.MailerBatches.FetchedMessage.PreProcessMessage()
   at Tridion.OutboundEmail.Services.Mailer.OutboundEmailMailer.HandleTestMessages(Dictionary`2 messages)
2018-02-27T09:10:53 [Error] ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: oracle.xml.sql.OracleXMLSQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLSAVE", line 115
ORA-06512: at "SH_OEDB.MAILINGS_SAVE_LINKURLS", line 15
ORA-06512: at line 1
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.DataSession.OpenRecordsetByStoredProcedure(UserContext userContext, String sProcName, Dictionary`2 parameters, Dictionary`2 outputParameters, Int32 timeoutSeconds)
2018-02-27T09:10:53 [Error] Stored procedure failed: SP_MAILINGS_SAVE_LINKURLS
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.DataSession.OpenRecordsetByStoredProcedure(UserContext userContext, String sProcName, Dictionary`2 parameters, Dictionary`2 outputParameters, Int32 timeoutSeconds)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.MailingDal.SaveLinkUrls(TcmUri mailingURI, EmailLinkUrls linkUrls)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.MailerBatches.FetchedMessage.UpdateTmsLinksInRenderdContent()
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.MailerBatches.FetchedMessage.PreProcessMessage()
   at Tridion.OutboundEmail.Services.Mailer.OutboundEmailMailer.HandleTestMessages(Dictionary`2 messages)
2018-02-27T09:10:53 [Error] ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
ORA-06512: at "SH_OEDB.MAILINGS_SAVE_LINKURLS", line 12
ORA-06512: at line 1
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.DataSession.OpenRecordsetByStoredProcedure(UserContext userContext, String sProcName, Dictionary`2 parameters, Dictionary`2 outputParameters, Int32 timeoutSeconds)
```

we have tried to increase the cursor limit on OE database but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

There were some emails with malformed links stuck in QUEUED_EMAILS_MESSAGES table after clearing those emails mailer service started working fine.

Comment: In that case, might I suggest accepting your own answer so the question becomes "closed"?

Comment: I don't really see the connection between "malformed links" and hitting the limit on the number of open cursors in Oracle. If you could provide us with more details, perhaps we can make sure it doesn't happen in the future.

Comment: @PeterKjaer if u see the error logs open cursors are exceeding while executing SP "SH_OEDB.MAILINGS_SAVE_LINKURLS " so i guess it is because of  creating tracking URL without specifying title for it.i don't have other information apart from this logs.